# C++ multiple inheritance and pure functions

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, pure-virtual

I'm a bit confused about a "multiple inheritance problem". Consider the following hunk of code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct iface
{
    virtual void foo () = 0;
    virtual ~iface () {}
};

struct wrapped
{
    virtual void foo ()
    {
        std::cerr << "wrapped\n";
    }
};

struct impl : public wrapped, public iface
{
};

iface* factory ()
{
    return new impl;
}

int main ()
{
    iface *object = factory ();

    object->foo();

    delete object;

    return 0;
}
```

This is abstracted out of some code that's using the pimpl idiom. The idea is that `wrapped` is some complicated class with all sorts of other bells and whistles. `iface` just makes a particular facet of `wrapped` visible and the `factory()` function builds an `impl` class that implements `iface` by using `wrapped`. In my real code, the `wrapped` class comes from a library with an enormous tree of headers, so I define `impl` in a separate compilation unit to avoid the rest of my application having to pull them in.

Anyway, what I pasted does not compile, and gives the following error:

```
$ g++ -o test test.cc
test.cc: In function ‘iface* factory()’:
test.cc:23:16: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘impl’
     return new impl;
                ^
test.cc:17:8: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘impl’:
 struct impl : public wrapped, public iface
        ^
test.cc:5:18: note:     virtual void iface::foo()
     virtual void foo () = 0;
                  ^
```

Obviously, I can avoid the error by writing a concrete implementation of `foo` in `impl` that forwards to `wrapped::foo()`, but I don't understand why the compiler doesn't pick up the implementation from the `wrapped` class.

I assume that somehow the "foo" from `iface` and the "foo" from `wrapped` end up being different when doing name resolution (is that the right word) for `impl`, but I don't really understand why.

Can someone explain what's going on?

Comment: Exactly *that* is going on: wrapped::foo() doesn't magically map to iface::foo(). They're two distinct types. When used as an "iface", the compiler must be able to resolve iface::foo(), it can't just guess that the inherited wrapped::foo() is the one to call, you'll have to give an implementation.

Comment: Yep, that makes sense. I suppose the problem is that `impl` is "downstream" from both `iface` and `wrapped`, so there's no way to convince the two of them that their `foo` functions should have the same resolved name (if that's the correct terminology). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If any virtual function of a class is a pure virtual then the class is absrtract.
Class impl has two member functions with the same name

```
iface::foo
```

and

```
wrapped::foo
```

The first member function of class impl is pure virtual, so the class is abstract. The compiler may not create an object of an abstract class.

Comment: Right. Sorry, I probably wasn't clear enough in my question. What I was trying to understand was whether it was possible for my `impl` class to be declared so that the two functions got the same name. Apparently not.

Comment: Anyway, thanks. This is correct and (with Willem van Rumpt's comment) I now understand what's going on. Thank you both for the help.

Answer (score 1):

`impl` has two entirely separate methods, `iface::foo`, which is pure, and `wrapped::foo`. There's no name resolution — virtual function calls are dispatched by a structure called vtable, which holds pointers to implementations. A class has separate vtable for each of its direct ancestors, at least in cases without virtual inheritance. Synonymous virtual functions from different ancestors end up in different vtables; the compiler has no way of "combining" them. C++ doesn't have mixins.

> Obviously, I can avoid the error by writing a concrete implementation of foo in impl that forwards to wrapped::foo()

Better yet, don't use double inheritance — do something like

```
struct impl : public iface
{
    virtual void foo ()
    {
        wr.foo ();
    }
private:
    wrapped wr;
};
```

Comment: Quite seriously: Why do you believe that storing an object is a better solution? I understand some problems with multiple inheritance (diamond diagrams etc.), but I assumed that the example above was exactly the sort of problem multiple inheritance was designed to solve. I should say that I come from a lisp background, where the object system is considerably more flexible (and correspondingly slower), so some of the "don't do that!" advice in C++ circles is rather confusing for me.

Comment: You shouldn't use multiple inheritance because it's confusing and achieves nothing that can't be done by simple aggregation. Some features of C++ are poorly designed.

You can use pointer if `wrapper` is heavy.

Comment: OK. We're going to fundamentally disagree about this design choice, so I'll leave the conversation there. Thank you for clarifying.